Installing Drush 12 globally
We're trying to install a global Drush 12 installation for a Linux Debian server hosting multiple Drupal 10 websites in different folders.
We've tried simply doing a composer require drush/drush in a specific folder, for instance /var/drush but reading issues people are having online it seems that Drush 12 is not able to run on its own and requires a minimal Drupal project to function. Without that project, we keep getting the error message:
[pre-flight] Package "drupal/core" is not installed

So instead we did:
composer require drupal/core-recommended
composer require drush/drush

Which creates a dummy project, and seems to have enough code for Drush to run.
But our websites are not there, so we're trying to run Drush with the --root=/path/to/one/website for instance, but it seems to simply ignore the option. There's no error message, no warning, even with -vvvvv option. Drush seems to be permanently stuck with its dummy project.
We've tried defining aliases in the configuration following the documentation online, using the multiple different methods, but that configuration is also ignored, with no error or warning messages.
Is it no longer possible to have a global Drush installation with Drush 12? Do we really need to have Drush 12 installed on each and every website for it to function?

Yes the only supported way is to have it as a composer requirement on each drupal install. It's all there in the docs:
https://www.drush.org/12.5.2/install/
Drush only supports one install method. It requires that your Drupal site be built with Composer and Drush be listed as a dependency.

Ah well, I thought there might still be a path to have a global install. Thanks for the clarification.
